# How to sum two columns and compare with another column of the same table

Tags: sql-server-2012

Im fairly new to SQL.

I have a table called Entity and that Entity have 4 columns, id, valone, valtwo, valthree.

What Im trying to accomplish is sum valone with valtwo and check if that SUM is less than valthree.

So we have `SUM(valone + valtwo)`
and check `WHERE SUM(valone + valtwo) < valthree`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you actually trying to sum these figures (are you aggregating)? If so, what's your criteria for the sum? Sample data and expected output would really help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` is an aggregation function, and not what you need here. You need a row by row function, which is simply `+`:

```
SELECT *, valone + valtwo
FROM dbo.Entity
WHERE valone + valtwo < valthree
;
```